# React search by name

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hello I am currently fetching through an API call to search by name in my search bar. I'm having an error of [image] whenever I type a string in my search bar.

This is my postman URL **/product/list/search?search=assorted** where I can fetch names with "assorted"

I'm fetching it in frontend like this

```
export const searchProducts = async (query) => {
  return await get(`product/list/search=?${query})
}
```

and this is how I implement it on my search page

```
const SearchPage = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllProducts().then((products) => {
      setProducts(products)
    })
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadProducts = async () => {
      const query = await searchProducts(query)
      setQuery(query)
    }
    loadProducts()
  }, [query])

  return (
    <>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={1}>
          <Box pt={1.5}>
            <Link to="#">
              <ArrowBackIcon className={classes.backSize} />
            </Link>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={11}>
          <Paper className={classes.root}>
            <IconButton aria-label="menu"></IconButton>
            <InputBase
              className={classes.input}
              placeholder="Search for foods"
              onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
              value={query}
            />
            <IconButton aria-label="search">
              <SearchIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Box pt={1}>
        <CategoryList categories={categories} />
      </Box>
      <Box pt={1}>
        <ProductList products={products} />
      </Box>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: please add response from search api. most of issues relate to < token with JSON is server response html instead. and: does not use same name of variable, it is not good `const query = await searchProducts(query)`. better to use `debound` function for typing search like this

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with `/` at the beginning?

```
export const searchProducts = async (query) => {
  return await get(`/product/list/search?search=${query}`)
}
```

Comment: Can you show the definition/implementation of the function `get`?

Comment: const get = async (_url) => {
  return await fetch(`${API}/${_url}`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json()
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}

Comment: So maybe your server is not returning JSON, but HTML or a simple string.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your postman window? So I will be able to see it. You can use https://imgbb.com/

Comment: Hi, this is the sample https://imgur.com/nCHGNvV postman result.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. The error that you are getting is because you run the response.json() function and it will throw the error if we can not parse the response to the JSON.  It is very common when server is returning text or HTML instead of json.

Comment: I have 10 mins, so maybe we can try tools teamviewer and finally solve your problem :D

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see your postman api call and the one in the await doesn't seems to be matching - it should be

await get(`product/list/search?search=${query}`);

Comment: I tried this but when I'm typing it erases whenever I type any character in the search field.

Comment: Can you please provide api call and its response, from what i can see as 'query' is the dependency in the useEffect, the searchProducts might be getting called for every keystroke. It's better to use debouncing or have a setTimeout for let's say 2 sec so that user can type the word to search

Comment: const get = async (_url) => {
  return await fetch(`${API}/${_url}`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json()
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}